# Can't find zlib when installing other libs with brew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm am new to both `*nix` and `brew`.

I tried to install many things using Homebrew, but it keeps saying:

```
configure: error: *** Working zlib library and headers not found ***
```

Then I tried install `zlib` again, but it said:

```
Warning: zlib-1.2.8 already installed
```

Here's the log gist including `brew --config` and `echo $PATH`.

### https://gist.github.com/bearzk/7491631

**UPDATE:**

I have tried reinstalling `zlib` and stuff that were mentioned in the output, but sadly nothing happened.

I really don't know what all these things are..not sure if I should delete or reserve :(

---

Anyone has a idea how should I solve this?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: See what `brew doctor` says. Also try to reinstall zlib.

Comment: Note that it says "zlib library and headers". Not sure about brew, but in most packaging systems, headers are in a separate package, usually called something similar to "zlib-dev", and the configure tests will only work when this package is installed (the test compiles and links a program, for which a package containing just runtime libraries is insufficient).

Answer (score 0):

Tried editing the post with update with content from `config.log`, it said I have less than 10 reputation to post more than 2 links, so I put it here:

https://gist.github.com/bearzk/7493781

Here's the content of `config.log` from `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/glib`

---

The **reason** for the problem I had with homebrew is that I had some 32bit libraries installed in a 64bit system, if you also have similar problem, remember to check in this direction too.

The **solution** is to move all the mentioned file to other place and do a `brew prune` to remove unnecessary files, in my case there's also some linking conflicts with `glib`, so I did a `brew link --overwrite glib` to do a force link.

Now the homebrew says everything is up-to-date and ready to brew :)